# Как уменьшить убийство моего SSD с помощью MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Вопрос - какие настройки поменять в конфигах MYSQL чтобы мой диск расходовал меньше свой ресурс.

Расход до использования **2-3 Гб/сутки.** Сейчас расходуется порядка **15-20 Гб/сутки.**

Может кто-нибудь подскажет?
Можно было бы даже делать запись 1-2 раза в сутки а остальное держать в RAM.
База не очень большая.

Comment: А почему бы не начать с оптимизации sql-запросов, вызывающих запись?

Comment: Потому что я не являюсь инженером по базам данных. Данные таковы, что их утеря не несет критического характера. Следовательно можно пренебречь частым использованием диска и увеличением использования памяти.

Comment: Почему бы не обратиться к инженеру по базам данных? :)

Comment: Почему бы вам не перестать замусоривать ресурс давая ответы, который от вас не ждут?

Comment: Потому что всё выглядит так, что вы хотите от MySQL того, для чего он ни разу не предназначен. Вообще, MySQL вроде как не предназначена для хранения данных в памяти. Для вещей, которые не жалко потерять и которые предпочтительнее хранить в памяти, обычно используют какой-нибудь Redis. Вместо того, чтобы скрывать симптомы, лучше устранить причину и переделать то, что у вас вызывает много записи.

Comment: И да, я не давал ответы. Это поле для комментариев.

Comment: Логично, но настройки MySQL могут менять принцип работы БД.

Comment: Делайте в памяти виртуальный диск и туда базы размещайте. Вот вам и решение.